# How to deploy a dockerized php application

Tags: php, docker, linode

I have a Laravel application and docker setup for local development using `docker-compose`. My source code for the application is kept in BitBucket and now I would like to deploy the application to a Linode instance and serve it from the docker system. How this can be done ? As of now I have a LAMPP image running in Linode and I push my source code to the corresponding path when deployment is triggered. Now I would like to use the same docker image in the server instead of the LAMPP server I am using. How this can be done ? Or this is the correct method of doing it ?

It will be helpful if someone can point out a tutorial or guide for doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are locked on staying with linode, I would try one of these options:

- [Linode docker machine driver](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/linode/) - note that this is a non official docker machine driver.
- [Linode containers guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/containers/) - using Kubernetes, which I usually try to avoid for my small-scale apps.

If you are NOT locked on staying with linode, and you wish to avoid the complexities of Kubernetes, I can tell you I have had success with running a docker machine on Digital Ocean - this solution (as most other docker-machine solutions) makes deployment as easy as running it locally.

- [List of docker machine drivers](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/)
- [Digital Ocean docker machine guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-provision-and-manage-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-machine-on-ubuntu-16-04)

As for how to get your code PHP code to the container, here is an example `Dockerfile` I have been using for one of my PHP dockerized apps:

```
FROM php:7-apache

# Packages
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install git zip
RUN a2enmod rewrite && docker-php-ext-install sockets

# App
COPY . .

# Composer
COPY private/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN [[ ! -f composer.json ]] || composer install --ansi --no-interaction
```

You can adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Do I need to deploy the source code with the docker or I can do it through the deployment system that I have been using ?

Comment: When dealing with docker, you have everything that the app needs to run inside the docker image. When we are dealing with compiled languages (like Go), then no (the image will only contain the compiled binary). When dealing with PHP - yes, I have updated the answer.